# Нужно ли обособлять оборот со словом "благодаря" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> *Благодаря регулярному обмену информацией российских таможенников с иностранными коллегами, а также работе представителей таможенного ведомства в других странах, с начала 2018 года ФТС довзыскала в бюджет более 8,5 миллиона рублей таможенных платежей с физических лиц.*

Нужно ли обособлять оборот со словом "благодаря" в данном случае (нужна ли запятая после слов "в других странах")? Если да, то как объяснить необходимость запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделение оборота необходимо по причине его распространенности; только с помощью
запятой можно обозначить границу этого оборота и тем самым избежать двусмысленности.